# 【Need Help】XML Error: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I was using waybackmachine to see the website, but had a problem.

When I open it, it says; error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

This is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<script src="//archive.org/includes/analytics.js?v=cf34f82" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){var v=archive_analytics.values;v.service='wb';v.server_name='wwwb-app44.us.archive.org';v.server_ms=755;archive_analytics.send_pageview({});});</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_static/js/playback.bundle.js?v=xTFGO54E" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_static/js/wombat.js?v=UHAOicsW" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  __wm.init("https://web.archive.org/web");
  __wm.wombat("https://vtt.tumblr.com/tumblr_p4fwq5Fzyd1wlqe5m.mp4","20190111114507","https://web.archive.org/","web","/_static/",
          "1547207107");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid XML because XML can only have on root tag.